# How to alternate background color of a table view using QSS?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, qtstylesheets

The example-code below creates a single QTableView.

[image]

Question: How to modify this code to make odd-numbered Items background color grey and even-numbered items black. Should CSS's `alternate-background-color` be used? With that flags?

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)        
        self.items=['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        item=str(self.items[index.row()])

        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return item
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item
        if role==QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.white))

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role!=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:   return QtCore.QVariant()
        if orientation==QtCore.Qt.Horizontal: return QtCore.QVariant('My Column Name') 

class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)        

        myModel=TableModel()
        self.setModel(myModel)      

        appStyle="""
        QTableView
        {   
            background-color: black;
            gridline-color:black;
            color: black;
            selection-color: black;
        }
        QTableView::item 
        {   
            color: white;
            background:black;            
        }
        QTableView::item:hover
        {   
            color: black;
            background:#ffaa00;            
        }
        QTableView::item:focus
        {   
            color: black;
            background:#0063cd;            
        }        
        """
        self.setStyleSheet(appStyle)

view=TableView()
view.show()   
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I can't comment for PyQt specifically, but the one caveat with storing your backgrounds in the model, is that they will trickle down to all views.  If you want to display the same data in different ways (the essence of MVC) you'll need to do it in a delegate (reimplementing paint()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to control Item's background color using a model. CSS is used later for everything else:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)        
        self.items=['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        item=str(self.items[index.row()])

        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return item
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item
        if role==QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.white))
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if index.row()%2:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor("#242424"))
            else:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black))

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role!=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:   return QtCore.QVariant()
        if orientation==QtCore.Qt.Horizontal: return QtCore.QVariant('My Column Name') 

class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)        

        myModel=TableModel()
        self.setModel(myModel)      

        appStyle="""
        QTableView
        {   
            background-color: black;
            gridline-color:grey;
            color: black;
        }
        QTableView::item 
        {   
            color: white;         
        }
        QTableView::item:hover
        {   
            color: black;
            background: #ffaa00;            
        }
        QTableView::item:focus
        {   
            color: black;
            background: #0063cd;            
        }        
        """
        self.setStyleSheet(appStyle)

view=TableView()
view.show()   
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: don't forget to call  self.setAlternatingRowColors(True) or you'll be scratching your head like I was